# The parabola with the equation $y=-x^2+4x+8$ is shifted so that it passes through the points (1,1) and (3,5). Find the equation of the new parabola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Given the points $(1,1)$ and $(3,5)$, the vertex form would be:
$1=(1-h)^2+k$  for $(1,1)$  and
$5=(3-h)^2+k$  for $(3,5)$.
With a system of equations, I obtain that $h = 1$ and $k = 1$, so the new formula of the shifted parabola would be: $y=(x-1)^2+1$

What I don't understand is the answer of my exercise sheet, which says that the new equation would be $y= -x^2+6x-4$

Can someone help me understand this?
Thanks

Comment: How did you determined these equations? This is not how the shift works

Comment: The equation $ y = (x-h)^2 + k $, or equivalently $ y - k = (x-h)^2 $, corresponds to shifting the canonical "upwards" parabola $ y = x^2 $ by the vector $ (h, k) $. You can see that $ x $ was replaced by $ x-h $ and $ y $ by $ y - k $. But this is not the parabola that you want to shift. You need to start with the one given by the problem.

Comment: There are both an "upward-opening" and a "downward-opening" parabola with a specific absolute-value of the quadratic coefficient $ \ a \ $ that contains two given points.  The statement of the problem indicates that you want to use the "_downward_-opening" parabola $ \ y \ = \ -(x-h)^2 + k \ \ . \ $  Your method then correctly gives $ \ h \ = \ 3 \ $ and $ \ k \ = \ 5 \ \ , $ which corresponds to the given answer.  (You don't actually need to spend any further time dealing with the initial parabola, since you aren't asked for the amounts of the shifts.)

Comment: As boojum has explained, the general equation of a parabola is $y = a(x - h)^2 + k$. There are three unknowns, so you would need at least three equations to find the equation normally. (Just as two points define a line, three points are needed to define a unique quadratic.) However, as you know the quadratic is only translated and not stretched/reflected, you can observe that $a = -1$ to match the coefficient in front of $x^2$, which is $-1$. From there on, your method works fine.

Comment: You are shifting the wrong parabola.  You are shifting $y = x^2$.   The parabola you are *supposed* to shift is $-x^2 + 4x + 8$.  So if you shift it by $h$ and $k$ you should get $-(x-h)^2+4(x-h) + 8 + k$.  Now start over and do it.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a function, its graph has equation $$y=f(x).$$
Shifting this graph horizontally by $a\in \Bbb R$ and vertically by $b\in \Bbb R$ yields to the graph of equation
$$
y = f(x-a)+b.
$$
Here, you have the parabola of equation $y=f(x)$ with $f(x)=-x^2 + 4x + 8$.
Its shift by $(a,b)$ has then equation
$$
y = -(x-a)^2 + 4(x-a) + 8 + b.
$$
You can now solve this exercise by substituting $(x,y) = (1,1)$ and $(x,y) = (3,5)$ and solve for $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

The original parabola is

$ y = - x^2 + 4 x + 8 $

Shifting by $(h, k)$ gives the parabola,

$ y = - (x - h)^2 + 4 (x - h) + 8 + k $

Points $(1,1)$ and $(3,5)$ are on the new parabola, so

$ 1 = - (1 - h)^2 + 4 (1 - h) + 8 + k $

$ 5 = - (3 - h)^2 + 4 (3 - h) + 8 + k $

Substracting,

$ - 4 = - (1^2 - 3^2 - 2 h (1 - 3 )) + 4 (1 - 3) $

$ - 4 = - (-8 + 4 h ) - 8 $

Therefore,

$ -8 + 4 h = - 4 $

From which

$ 4 h = 4 $

Hence, $ h = 1$.

Now substitute this into one of the new parabola equations to find $k$.

$ 1 = - (1 - 1)^2 + 4 (1 - 1) + 8 + k $

Therefore, $ k = -7 $

Now the equation of the new parabola is

$ y = - (x - 1)^2 + 4 (x - 1) + 8 + (-7) $

Expanding, this becomes

$ y = - x^2 +6 x - 4 $

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach.

Assuming that a "shift" strictly means a translation, then the vector between points $A = (1,  1)$ and $B = (3, 5)$, which is $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ is preserved. Thus the following system of equations holds:

$$\begin{cases} b = -a^2 + 4a + 8 \\ b + 4 = -(a + 2)^2 + 4(a + 2) + 8 \end{cases} \tag{2}$$

and this gives $4 = -(a + 2)^2 - (-a^2) + 4(a + 2) - 4a$ or $4 = -4a - 4 + 8 \implies a = 0$, and $b = 8$.

Hence the point $A$ corresponds to $(0, 8)$ on the original quadratic, and so the new quadratic is a translation of $1$ unit to the right and $7$ units down.

Therefore the equation of the new parabola is:

$$y = -(x - 1)^2 + 4(x - 1) + 8 - 7 = -(x^2 - 2x + 1) + 4x - 4 + 1$$
$$ = \boxed{-x^2+ 6x - 4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

"Shifted" here means translated.
In particular, after being shifted by $p$ units in the $y$ direction and $q$ units in the $x$ direction, the shifted parabola satisfies the equation
$$
(y-p)
= (x - q)^2 + 4(x - q) + 8.
$$

Now, the problem is to solve the above for $p$ and $q$ such that $(x, y)  =(1, 1)$ and $(3, 5)$ satisfy the equation.
Substituting these points, we find that
\begin{align*}
1 - p
&= -(1-q)^2 - 4(1 - q) + 8, \\
5 - p
&= -(3-q)^2 - 4(3 - q) + 8.
\end{align*}

Expanding these yeilds
\begin{align*}
p &= q^2 + 2q - 10, \\
p &= q^2 - 2q - 6,
\end{align*}
which we can solve to find $p = -7, q = 1$, which corresponds to the equation
\begin{align*}
(y + 7)
&= (x - 1)^2 + 4(x - 1) + 8,\\
y
&= -x^2 + 6x - 4.
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean to write $y - p = -(x - q)^2 + 4(x - q) + 8$?